# .htaccess 301 redirect rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

can someone tell me how to write rewrite rule: I have many links that look like:

http://www.mavrica.com/index.php?eID=tx_cms_showpic&file=uploads%252Fpics%252Fmozic_05.jpg&width=800m&height=600m&bodyTag=%253Cbody%2520bgcolor%253D%2522black%2522%253E&wrap=%253Ca%2520href%253D%2522javascript%253Aclose()%253B%2522%253E%2520%257C%2520%253C%252Fa%253E&md5=025892981ebd7f312b96276beb3ee194

I would like to redirect all of them to `http://www.mavrica.com/fotogalerije/`

All the links have in common first part (up to tx_cms_showpic).

I tried the following `htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteRule /index.php?eID=tx_cms_showpic$ http://mavrica.com/fotogalerije/ [R=301]
```

and with

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php?eID=tx_cms_showpic(.*) http://www.mavrica.com/fotogalerije/
```

but none of them work.

What have I missed out?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try `RewriteRule /index.php?eID=tx_cms_showpic(.*)$ http://mavrica.com/fotogalerije/ [R=301]`

Comment: Tried, but no success. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to capture and/or match the query string part of the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?eID=tx_cms_showpic [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mavrica.com/fotogalerije/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @user2123280 so your folder does not exist?

Comment: I guess it is also redirected. My cms `typo3` does that.

Comment: @user2123280 try this one